# Finding all the hard-links of a file without traversing the file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-link, inode

I have seen [in this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html) that inodes have a **link counter** to know how many files (read: "directory entry") point to this inode. Is there a way to know which directories contain such entries without traversing the whole file system? Is this information stored somewhere?

```
struct inode {
    kdev_t                       i_dev;
    unsigned long                i_ino;
    umode_t                      i_mode;
    nlink_t                      i_nlink;
    uid_t                        i_uid;
    gid_t                        i_gid;
    …
};
```

Comment: The fastest method - with traversal only - might be `find -inum <n> -samefile path`.

Comment: @ott-- `find` is used with **either** `-inum` **or** `-samefile` but not with both.

Comment: @HaukeLaging you're right, only one of them.

Answer (score 14):

No. Directory entries pointing to inodes are one-way links. The inodes do not point back to the directory entries.

In order to find a complete list of directory entries that point to an inode, you need to traverse the filesystem until you have found enough directory entries to account for the inode's link count.