# check if there is a link from the current file

Tags: symlink, ln

How can I check if there is a link from the current file on Linux?
Say, I have:

```
touch foo
ln -s foo bar
ll foo bar
 bar -> foo
 foo
```

Now, I want to know, if there are any file linked from `foo`:e.g.

```
$magic-command foo
foo<-bar
```

Comment: Do answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184849/symbolic-link-find-all-files-that-link-to-this-file) help you?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find`, you can do:

```
find -L /  -xtype l -prune -samefile foo -exec ls -ld {} +
```

That will find all the files of type symlinks which eventually resolve to the same file as `foo`. That will also include symlinks to symlinks or hardlinks to `foo`<sup>1</sup>.

With `-L`, symlinks are followed. We want that to `find` files linked to `foo`, but we don't want to follow symlink when descending the directory tree. Hence the `-prune` that stops descending into symlinks.

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
ls -ld /**/*(@De:'[[ $REPLY -ef foo ]]':)
```

If you're only interested in symlinks.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Finding *only* files that are symlinks to `foo` would be more complicated. The `-samefile`/`-ef` compare the device and inode numbers returned by the `stat()` system call, that is after *all* symlinks have been resolved (by the system). What you would want is check for links whose target's directory is the same as that of `foo` and base name is `foo`.

With `zsh`, that would be:

```
zmodload zsh/zstat
links_to_thefile() {
  local file link
  file=${1-$REPLY}
  zstat -L -A link +link -- $file || return
  [[ $link:t = $thefile:t ]] || return
  case $link in
    (/*) file=$link;;
    (*)  file=$file:h/$link
  esac
  [[ $file:h -ef $thefile:h ]]
}

thefile=foo
ls -ld /**/*(@D+links_to_thefile)
```

Or with GNU tools (`find` and shell (`bash`)):

```
find / -type l  \( -lname foo -o -lname '*/foo' \) -printf '%p\0%l\0' |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file && IFS= read -rd '' link; do
    [[ $link = /* ]] || link=${file%/*}/$link
    [[ ${link%/*} -ef . ]] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
  done
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't find symlinks on filesystems that are not currently mounted, or that are in directories that the process doesn't have permission to access.

Answer (score 0):

`stat` doesn't count symlink counts, hardlinks though - if that helps.

[There's no way to resolve what you're asking.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75511/finding-all-the-hard-links-of-a-file-without-traversing-the-file-system/75529#75529)