# How to find if a directory is having a symbolic link as well with any other names

Tags: linux, bash, directory, shell-script, find

```
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 oracle   oinstall    10 Oct 14 03:47 abc -> xyz
drwxr-xr-x.   6 oracle   oinstall     4 Oct 26 21:11 xyz
```

i want to find that xyz is having a symbolic link with name abc

Comment: To paraphrase your question: "Given a file/directory, how can I find any symbolic link to it?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if there is a link from the current file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/289694) or [thoroughly find all links (hard and symlinks, and any combination thereof) leading to a file/dir](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/99271)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if there is a link from the current file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289694/check-if-there-is-a-link-from-the-current-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the links named `abc` to a file `xyz` are in current directory this could be done with:

```
find -L / -samefile `readlink -f xyz` -name abc
```

`readlink -f xyz` can be replaced with a full path to a file (which it does in fact for the file in current directory).

If you know exact link name, but instead want to find just all the links to a file `xyz` with any names, you could just omit `name` like this:

```
find -L / -samefile `readlink -f xyz`
```

You can also add `2> /dev/null` at the end of the command to suppress "permission denied" warnings.

Comment: what if they don't know the name of the link?

Comment: @ilkkachu OP asked "is having a symbolic link **with name abc**". I've offered a solution to find links named exactly `abc`. If he wants to find **all links** to the file `xyz`, when the `-name abc` part of the find command could be just omitted.

Comment: the words "_to find that_" would imply that the fact in question isn't supposed to be known beforehand, but is exactly what they're trying to find out.

Comment: @ilkkachu maybe you're right, sorry not a native English here. I've updated my answer to reflect both options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no back reference or count of symbolic links maintained to a file or directory.

So, for example, it would be perfectly valid to delete the xyz directory.
The presence of any symbolic links wouldn't prevent this, nor would it prevent the data in xyz from being destroyed. Any symbolic links would only be recognised as being invalid if an attempt was made to open them -- they would become "broken links".

The situation would be substantially different for **hard links**.

Comment: It’s not clear to me that this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 - **/*(ND@e['[[ $REPLY -ef xyz ]]'])
```

Would `print` `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn the files of type symlink (`@`) with any name (`*`), under and level of subdirectories (`**/`), including hidden ones (`D`), not complaining if there's no match (`N`), and that are the same file as `xyz` after symlink resolution (`-ef`).

Note it would also report symlinks to another symlink or hardlink to `xyz`.

---

If you just wanted to find symlinks whose target is the literal string `xyz`, then it's just:

```
find . -lname xyz
```